# How to take the screenshot of the page using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, screenshot

I need to take the screenshot of the page. I can take the screenshot of the page using Google API.

Like if I enter the `URL=mydomain.com/` then it's working but if I used the `URL=mydomain.com/new/index/6` then I am getting the error

> Warning: file_get_contents(www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=mydomain.com/new/index/6&screenshot=true): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in

Would you help me out in this?

```
<?php 
//website url
$siteURL = "mydomain.com/new/index/6";
//call Google PageSpeed Insights API
$googlePagespeedData = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=$siteURL&screenshot=true");
//decode json data
$googlePagespeedData = json_decode($googlePagespeedData, true);

//screenshot data
$screenshot = $googlePagespeedData['screenshot']['data'];
$screenshot = str_replace(array('_','-'),array('/','+'),$screenshot); 

//display screenshot image
echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,".$screenshot."\" />";
 ?>
```

Comment: check the permissions for everything after the public area

Comment: you may also have to include a trailing slash `$siteURL = "mydomain.com/new/index/6/";` give that a try and make sure there is an index file in that folder.

Comment: It looks like you're concatenating your URL in to the Google URL. Try using `urlencode($siteURL)`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried trailing slash but same issue

Comment: @timclutton, I tried that also but am issue

Comment: It could also be because of a possible reserved keyword for folder/filename conventions, being "index". I work on quite a few servers and one in particular won't let me use certain words, one such as "icon" if my memory serves me right. This could be anything though, so that's about the scope of my knowledge on this one. @NarendraVerma check file/folder permissions settings also.

Answer (score 3):

```
"message": "Invalid value 'mydomain.com/new/index/6'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?i)http(s)?://.*'",
```

Just try to add protocol in **$siteURL**

Something like this:

```
$siteURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137304/how-to-take-the-screenshot-of-the-page-using-php";
```

Comment: Gah, ninja'd! :)

Comment: @dekameron,  If I used like mydomain.com/new/index.php then it's working but If I use mydomain.com/new/index.php/6 than it's not working

Comment: @NarendraVerma so, check if "mydomain.com/new/index.php/6" is a valid URL with 200 StatusCode, without redirects etc.

Comment: I have a pdf file in this URL mydomain.com/new/index.php/6. If I directly ented this URL than pdf is displaying

Comment: @dekameron, Where should I check it?

Comment: @NarendraVerma How google should take screenshot from PDF file?

Comment: @dekameron, I am so sorry. I don't know. I thought it will work if I try mydomain.com/new/index.php/6 but it is not working. any other suggestions

Comment: @NarendraVerma It won't work with a PDF.  The error message when you try is clear: "The URL was fetched, but nothing was rendered. Ensure that the URL points to an HTML page that loads successfully in a web browser."

Answer (score 1):

Trying the following URL in a browser gives an explicit error message:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=example.com/test/test&screenshot=true
```

> Invalid value 'example.com/test/test'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?i)http(s)?://.*'

Changing the URL to include a protocol fixes the problem:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=http://example.com/test/test&screenshot=true
```